# Send email with codeigniter and ajax: aborted request

Tags: ajax, email, codeigniter

I'm using ajax to send an email through a contact form in codeigniter. The ajax (jquery) part is:

```
var dataString = 'nome=' +  nome + '&msg=' + msg + '&email=' + email + '&secure=' + secure + '&mailto=' + mailto + '&ci_token=' + $.cookie("ci_csrfprotection_cookie");

$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url();?>/contact/send',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        timeout: 1000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
                if(msg.sent){
                    $('#feedback').html("<?php echo lang('email_sucesso'); ?>").delay(6000).hide('slow');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#feedback').html("<?php echo lang('email_erro'); ?>").delay(6000).hide('slow');
                        }
                        botao.attr('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
```

And the controller is:

```
public function send()
{
    if ($this->input->post('secure') != 'siteform') {
        echo lang('erro_no_js');
    }else{
        $this->load->library('email');

        $nome = $this->input->post('nome');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $msg = $this->input->post('msg');
        $mailto = $this->input->post('mailto');
        $secure = $this->input->post('secure');

        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
        $config['smtp_user'] = $this->settings['smtp_email'];
        $config['smtp_pass'] = $this->settings['smtp_password'];
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $this->email->initialize($config); 

        $this->email->from($email, $nome);
        $this->email->to($mailto);
        $this->email->subject('Contacto do site');
        $this->email->message($msg);
        if ($this->email->send()){
            echo json_encode(array("sent"=>TRUE));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("sent"=>FALSE));
        }
    }
}
```

This actually sends the email correctly but the ajax call gets aborted and I never get a message back.

But if I remove the `$this->email->send()` bit, I get the response correctly but, of course, the email isn't sent.

What am I missing here?

Note: I have CSRF enabled and it's working ok in other ajax calls that query the database.

Comment: did you check your ajax request with Firebug to see what you get back?

Comment: @beerwin yes the request gets aborted and returns nothing... but without the `$this->email->send()` it return the response correctly.

Comment: Try putting a console.log or an alert right after this line `if(msg.sent){` and see if your code is actually getting this far.

Comment: Also try echoing out msg.sent before the if statement to see what it actually returns.

Comment: have you checked your php error log?

Comment: @Catfish the console.log doesn't log anything even when putted before the if statement

Comment: @beerwin I don't know where to find the error log but the PHP part seems to work fine as the email is actually sent

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log, /var/log/httpd/error.log, or something similar

Comment: are you using linux, or windows (just for the error log part)

Comment: @beerwin ok I found it but no errors there related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting async to false like this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url();?>/contact/send',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        timeout: 1000,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){
                if(msg.sent){
                    $('#feedback').html("<?php echo lang('email_sucesso'); ?>").delay(6000).hide('slow');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#feedback').html("<?php echo lang('email_erro'); ?>").delay(6000).hide('slow');
                        }
                        botao.attr('disabled', false);
               }
         });
```

Another way to try would be to use the `complete` function rather than the success function and lease async to true (which is the default). I think the complete function waits without a browser lock, but i'm not 100% certain of this.

Comment: async: false makes it work! But, I get a browser lock during the process... Is there a reason this won't work asynchronously?

Comment: Someone please correct me if i'm wrong, but i'm pretty sure it's because ajax is asynchronous and the javascript keeps executing without waiting for the php to return something. If you set asyn to false, it means that the ajax function will wait til it hears from the php function.

Comment: This putted me in the right track! The problem is the timeout setting. I had it with 1000 and this was not enough for the PHP to send the e-mail. Setting it to a higher value (8000) solves this problem! Thanks Catfish!

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answers work, some may encounter the additional the problem that a php warning is thrown:

```
Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
settings.
```

The way you get around this is either by setting the timezone in your php.ini or by adding it manually to your codeigniter index.php.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Chicago');
```

See [Date error sending mail using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467687/date-error-sending-mail-using-codeigniter)