# Date error sending mail using codeigniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, date

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and 
you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone  
identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CET/1.0/no DST' instead

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 704
Line Number 709
```

Trying to send an email using codeigniter Email library I get this error.I think I should specify the date_default_timezone_set but I don't know where I have to specify it since I don't use date when I send mail.

Comment: I answerd you a minute ago , why opening a new question for the same problem? Edit your php.ini file as written, It will solve you all those errors.

Answer (score 3):

Either set `date.timezone` in your php.ini file, or if that isn't possible, use:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
```

in CodeIgniter's index.php file.